# How does Stack Overflow remember users' actions when they're not logged in?

Tags: discussion, login

How does Stack Overflow remember users' actions when they're not logged in? Do they track IP addresses?

Comment: Does it? (I wouldn't know, I'm always logged in anyway)

Answer (score 2):

Tracking user actions can be done using an IP address, but it is usually done with cookies.

Data about the user is stored on the user's computer in temporary Internet files. As long as the user doesn't clear/disable them, this data can be used to keep track of user information.

This is also how Stack Overflow knows who you are and automatically logs you in when you haven't visited the site for two days.

Answer (score 0):

They use a database or the browser session.